# Microservices: how to effectively deal with data dependencies between microservices

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, microservices

I am developing an application utilizing the microservices development approach with the mean stack.  I am running into a situation where data needs to be shared between multiple microservices.  For example, let's say I have user, video, message(sending/receiving,inbox, etc.) services.  Now the video and message records belong to an account record.  As users create video and send /receive message there is a foreign key(userId) that has to be associated with the video and message records they create. I have scenarios where I need to display the first, middle and last name associated with each video for example.  Let's now say on the front end a user is scrolling through a list of videos uploaded to the system, 50 at a time.  In the worst case scenario, I could see a situation where a pull of 50 occurs where each video is tied to a unique user.

There seems to be two approaches to this issue:

One, I make an api call to the user service and get each user tied to each video in the list.  This seems inefficient as it could get really chatty if I am making one call per video.  In the second of the api call scenario, I would get the list of video and send a distinct list of user foreign keys to query to get each user tied to each video.  This seems more efficient but still seems like I am losing performance putting everything back together to send out for display or however it needs to be manipulated.

Two, whenever a new user is created, the account service sends a message with the user information each other service needs to a fanout queue and then it is the responsibility of the individual services to add the new user to a table in it's own database thus maintaining loose coupling.  The extreme downside here would be the data duplication and having to have the fanout queue to handle when updates needs to be made to ensure eventual consistency.  Though, in the long run, this approach seems like it would be the most efficient from a performance perspective.

I am torn between these two approaches, as they both have their share of tradeoffs.  Which approach makes the most sense to implement and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also interested in this question.

First of all, scenario that you described is very common. Users, videos and messages definitely three different microservices. There is no issue in how you broke down system into pieces.

Secondly, there are multiple options, how to solve data sharing problem. Take a look at great article from auth0: https://auth0.com/blog/introduction-to-microservices-part-4-dependencies/

Answer (score 1):

Don't restrict your design decision to those 2 options you've outlined. The hardest thing about microservices is to get your head around what a service is and how to cut your application into chunks/services that make sense to be implemented as a 'microservice'.

Just because you have those 3 entities (user, video & message) doesn't mean you have to implement 3 services. If your actual use case shows that these services (or entities) depend heavily on each other to fulfil a simple request from the front-end than that's a clear signal that your cutting was not right.

From what I see from your example I'd design 1 microservice that fulfills the request. Remember that one of the design fundamentals of a microservice is to be as independent as possible.
There's no need to over complicate services, it's not SOA.

https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html -> great read!

Regards,
Lars

Comment: Agree broadly, however, I don't think the Lewis/Fowler article has anything much to say about service composition which is helpful to the OP here.

Comment: Disagree. There is no issue with how app was broken apart into microservices. All decisions are reasonable.

Comment: Questions, if the three microservices described above, were combined together into one service, could this potentially lead to creating a sort of larger monolithic service as more capabilities were created for the user to be affiliated with?  Unless you are saying to create a microservice that combined the data from the needed dependencies.

Comment: @tomredfern - The article is not focusing around this exact problem but it talks about the between service and context boundaries which is important to look at I think.

Comment: I like the article @SergeyYarotskiyhas posted in his answer but it too talks about "The case for merging services into one" if services get too chatty, which is what I tried to outline with my original answer.